# How do I return just one element from this output?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensor

I am using TensorFlow in Python. When making a prediction with my model, here is my input:

```
UberLyft_model.predict(my_UberLyft_encoded)
```

I get this output:

```
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 53ms/step
array([[16.11945]], dtype=float32)
```

But I simply want this output:

`16.11945`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
prediction = UberLyft_model.predict(my_UberLyft_encoded)
result = prediction[0][0]
print(result)
```